# html multiline comment not working in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am using python cgi to parse a word file and display an organized table on the web browser. The user then has the option to download the tables as a word document or an excel sheet.

What I am trying to do is just submit the current html of the page to another cgi script as a string (through a hidden form). However, Chrome keeps reading it as another html block even though I have tried commenting it out with `<!--` and `-->`. What ends up happening is that I get the same tables multiple times when I only want them to show up once.

I really do not know why Chrome is ignoring the comment signs. The `<!--` is on the first line and `-->` is on the very last line. Below is the hidden form produced by my cgi file:

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'htmlExcel' value = "<!--<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
    <style>

     /* Font Definitions */
     @font-face
        {font-family:"MS Mincho";
        panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}

      /* Lots of html here*/


      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

    <p class=MsoNormal>&nbsp;</p>

    </div>

</body></html> -->">
```

Comment: What's with the tags? Only [tag:html] appears to be relevant to what you've actually posted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing all the `"` in the string with `'`. I then surrounded the string I wanted to submit with `" "`. I ended up not using html comments at all. I am sure there is a better way, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

html comments end with `-->` which I can't see in that novel you posted

Comment: In the very last line there is the -->

Comment: sorry about that, did not see it when I first looked at it, my bad